# How to do universal links with svelte?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, ios-universal-links

So far we have the json prepared but we aren't sure where to put the .wellknown folder or file in order for the `index.html` file to recognize it

```
{
    "appLinks": {
      "details": [
        {
            "appID" : "****.com.---",
            "paths" : ["*"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

We have tried putting the files in the public folder and creating a new route and neither have worked

Comment: if this is a file that has to be added to the output, you can put it in the `/static` folder